# What does it mean ERROR code=-28, message=Activating best chain?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, blockchain.info

I am using insight-api for get block chain information. When i am trying to start insight i am getting error "ERROR code=-28, message=Activating best chain..." . I saw this error first time,please help me how to reslove this.

Full stack trace of error:

```
                v0.2.12
```

connection
info: insight server listening on port 3000 in development mode

```
error: ERROR code=-28, message=Activating best chain...
```

I am unable to understand error. i am using insight-api for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your node is still starting up, you need to wait until it is finished before using the RPC interface. The RPC message is telling you to call back later, which `insight-api` doesn't seem to be able to understand, simply waiting until the node is completely active is a suitable workaround. This may take a few minutes depending on your servers hardware, the `bitcoin-cli` tool supports automatically waiting for the interface to be available with the `-rpcwait` flag.